# Inserting values from db to local table in VBA

Tags: mysql, vba, stored-procedures

I'm executing my StoredProcedure like this:

```
    Dim qdef As DAO.QueryDef
    Set qdef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("")
    qdef.Connect = CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblE").Connect
    qdef.sql = "EXEC StoredProc @Param1 = " & Me.Param1
    qdef.Execute
```

Now what I'd like to do with the results (since this wouldn't work)..-
Is to Insert them into table: `TempTable`.

Structure of TempTable matches with the return values of the stored procedure.

How could I do something like: `'INSERT INTO TempTable (EXEC StoredProc)'` with a LOCAL table?

Answer (score 0):

you could write it in a tmp table in sql, open this table with a recordset and insert the values of the "SQL" tmp_table into your local temp table.

Maybe have a look here: [How to insert ADO Recordset into MS Access Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13712692/how-to-insert-ado-recordset-into-ms-access-table)

I hope i understanded your question correctly...